# Spring boot on Tomcat with external configuration

Tags: spring-boot, configuration, war, tomcat8

I can't find an answer to this question on stackoverflow hence im asking here so I could get some ideas.

I have a Spring Boot application that I have deployed as a war package on Tomcat 8. I followed this guide [Create a deployable war file](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-traditional-deployment.html) which seems to work just fine.

However the issue I am currently having is being able to externalize the configuration so I can manage the configuration as puppet templates.

In the project what I have is,

```
src/main/resources
                  -- config/application.yml
                  -- config/application.dev.yml
                  -- config/application.prod.yml
                  -- logback-spring.yml
```

So how can I possibly load `config/application.dev.yml` and `config/application.prod.yml` externally and still keep `config/application.yml` ? (contains default properties including `spring.application.name`)

I have read that the configuration is load in this order,

1. A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
2. The current directory
3. A classpath /config package
4. The classpath root

Hence I tried to load the configuration files from `/opt/apache-tomcat/lib` to no avail.

**What worked so far**

Loading via `export CATALINA_OPTS="-Dspring.config.location=/opt/apache-tomcat/lib/application.dev.yml"`

however **what I would like to know is**,

1. Find out why loading via `/opt/apache-tomcat/lib` classpath doesn't work.
2. And is there a better method to achieve this ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are correct about load order. According to [Spring boot documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-application-property-files)

> SpringApplication will load properties from **`application.properties`** files in the following locations and add them to the Spring Environment:
>
> - A /config subdirectory of the current directory.
> - The current directory
> - A classpath /config package
> - The classpath root
>
> The list is ordered by precedence (properties defined in locations higher in the list override those defined in lower locations).
>
> [Note]
> You can also use YAML ('.yml') files as an alternative to '.properties'.

This means that if you place your `application.yml` file to `/opt/apache-tomcat/lib` or `/opt/apache-tomcat/lib/config` it will get loaded.

> 1. Find out why loading via /opt/apache-tomcat/lib classpath doesn't work.

However, if you place `application.dev.yml` to that path, it will not be loaded because `application.dev.yml` is not filename Spring is looking for. If you want Spring to read that file as well, you need to give it as option
`--spring.config.name=application.dev` or `-Dspring.config.name=application.dev`.
**But I do not suggest this method**.

> 2. And is there a better method to achieve this ?

Yes. Use [Spring profile-specific properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/spring-boot-features.html#boot-features-external-config-profile-specific-properties). You can rename your files from `application.dev.yml` to `application-dev.yml`, and give `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` option. Spring will read both `application-dev.yml` and `application.yml` files, and profile specific configuration will overwrite default configuration.

I would suggest adding `-Dspring.profiles.active=dev` (or `prod`) [to `CATALINA_OPTS`](https://hesip.com/post/environment-with-spring-boot/) on each corresponding server/tomcat instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
    I have finally simplified solution for reading custom properties from external location i.e outside of the spring boot project. Please refer to below steps.
Note: This Solution created and executed windows.Few commands and folders naming convention may vary if you are deploying application on other operating system like Linux..etc.

         1. Create a folder in suitable drive.
         eg: D:/boot-ext-config

         2. Create a .properties file in above created folder  with relevant property key/values and name it as you wish.I created dev.properties for testing purpose.
         eg :D:/boot-ext-config/dev.properties

            sample values:
            dev.hostname=www.example.com


        3. Create a java class in your application as below
        ------------------------------------------------------
        import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.ConfigurationProperties;
        import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

        @PropertySource("classpath:dev.properties")
        @ConfigurationProperties("dev")
        public class ConfigProperties {
            private String hostname;

            //setters and getters
        }
        --------------------------------------------
         4. Add @EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class) to SpringBootApplication as below
        --------------------------------------------
        @SpringBootApplication
        @EnableConfigurationProperties(ConfigProperties.class)
        public class RestClientApplication {
            public static void main(String[] args)  {
                 SpringApplication.run(RestClientApplication.class, args);
        }
        }
        ---------------------------------------------------------
        5. In Controller classes we can inject the instance using @Autowired and fetch properties

        @Autowired
            private ConfigProperties configProperties;

        and access properties using getter method 
       System.out.println("**********hostName******+configProperties.getHostName());

Build your  spring boot maven project and run the below command to start application.

-> set SPRING_CONFIG_LOCATION=<path to your properties file>

->java -jar app-name.jar
```